# Правильное наследование классов в php

Tags: php, наследование

Есть к примеру 3 класса

**Db, Core, User**

Раньше я делал так наследование

*User наследовал Core, Core наследовал Db*

Сказали что это не правильно в корне, что так быть не должно.

Вот и возник вопрос, как же правильно наследовать?..

**Сейчас пробую вот так**

```
class User{
public $core, $db = null;

function __construct(){
    global $core, $db;
    $this->core = $core;
    $this->core = $db;
}

public function getTets(){
    echo $this->core->coreTest();
}
}
```

Всё работает как нужно, но вот вопрос: Как же правильно наследовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам скорее всего щас распишут портянки про ООП и то, как вы путаете наследование с композицией/агрегацией. Если кратко по теме: наследовать только для использования стороннего кода - идея плохая (потому что связанность там, где ее быть не должно). Ваш пример уже лучше, еще лучше он станет, если вы $core и $db будете засылать через параметры конструктора, а не через global (инжект). Через параметры конструктора имеет смысл передать то, без чего класс работать однозначно не сможет. Остальное можно сетерами отдельными инициализировать.

Comment: То есть будет $user = new User($core, $db); , и так в каждом классе где нужно применить что то из $core и что то из $db, верно?

Comment: Исходя из данного конкретного кода - да. В реальности конечно так тоже смотрится странновато. На фреймворках у всех свои Dependency Injection и там все уже решили за вас, если писать свое с нуля, то будет что-то вроде User + UserManager/UserService, если по феншую проектировать... Основная мысль была в том, что наследование (реальное, через extends) - это последнее дело, для которого должны быть серьезные причины.

Comment: Тем более наследование с более чем двумя уровнями, это точно повод задуматься над происходящим, потому что кто там где и кем будет перекрываться в плане методов - так сразу и не разберешься.